# Iframe in manage pacakge

Tags: appexchange, security-review, iframe

I want to create an appexchange app. In that app, external site page(other system's page) will be shown under salesforce tab. To show external site page in visualforce page/lightning component, i will have to make use of iframe tag.

Is it allowed to use iframe from security review perspective?

Please share your views on use of iframe inside manage package, their limitations/ weired behavior or any other alternate solution for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a managed package that passed its security review recently and has an iframe showing a page from an external site. Presumably the sandboxing of the content in the iframe means there isn't a security risk of that content interacting with other parts of the page.

Comment: Thanks Keith for the quick reply.
Do you have any document for using iframe in manage package? If you have it then please share the link it will really help us.

Comment: @HK I do not sorry.